# How to configure Jenkins for a multi-module maven project

Tags: configuration, maven, jenkins, multi-module

I have a maven multi-modul project. The structure looks like:

```
-modulA         (Main project)
   - pom.xml
-parentModul    (Aggregator)
   - pom.xml
   - ModulB     (Integration Test Project)
       -pom.xml
```

Package definition is like:

```
<project ...>
<modules>
    <module>../modulA</module>
    <module>ModulB</module>
</modules>
```

One of the moduls (ModulA) has the same hierarchy level, The other is in the parent modul.
I try to add a job in Jenkins to build all automatically. (clean package)..

How should I configure the job that parentModul finds the other modules and build the project.??

Comment: I'm a bit lost after your comments. "ModuleA" has the same hierarchy level" - the same as **which**? The pom fragment is from "parentModul", right? If "ModuleA" is checked into SVN separately, why do you compile it with "parentModule"? Finally: what exactly is your error message?

Answer (score 2):

Add another aggregator. Place modulA and parentModul in the same directory and one level above them, simply add another pom like this:

```
aggregator/
|- modulA/
|  |- pom.xml
|- parentModul/
|  |- modulB/
|  |  |- pom.xml
|  |- pom.xml
|- pom.xml
```

In the aggregator/pom.xml define a modules section as follows:

```
<project ...>
    <modules>
        <module>modulA</module>
        <module>parentModul</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: You can always restructure/refactor the directories in SVN. In my opinion, what you have seems incorrectly done.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use SVN Externals to assemble sane Maven project workspace from insane SVN structure even accross different svn servers. Using svn external is not an ideal solution as it will cause problems with maven release plugin and with CI's SCM polling in certain configuration. They tell you : "You should not use svn externals" as makes life more difficult. But so do leg cast and crutches but when you have broken leg (or svn structure that is fubar) you really do not mind the inconvenience.

There several ways of doing this, depending on your SVN structure and desired workspace structure:

1. `svn co modulA`
2. `cd modulA`
3. `svn propedit svn:externals .` **NB: Note the (curdir) dot  at the end of line!**
4. add following line: 
   parentModul http://path.to.your.svn.location.of.parentModul
5. svn ci -m "added externals for parent"
6. svn up

and the svn retrieves (and commits) you code to following workspace structure

```
modulA/
|  |- pom.xml
parentModul/
|- modulB/
|  |- pom.xml
|- pom.xml
pom.xml
```

Or you could add a new directory to SVN 'workplace' and add new pom.xml there and get all modules you could ever want via svn externals to one level (or to multiple levels).

Answer (score 0):

> In my case it is not possible to add another parent project. ModulA is already checked in SVN independently from the others.

This indicates that you're probably wrong in putting `moduleA` in the `<modules>` section. If `moduleA` has different life cycle, then you should include it as a dependency.